# Assign an object name to data.frames based on the values in a character vector

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I've got a list of data.frames and a vector of names I want to assign to the data.frames. `mylist` and `mynames` vector have the same length. `mylist[[i]]` should get the name which is in `mynames[i]`. So let's say:

```
mynames <- c("apple", "pear", "banana", "pineapple")
```

I don't want to access those data.frames with `mynames[[i]]`, but I want to create the data.frames `apple` `pear` `banana` `pineapple`. How is that possible?

p.s. no reproducible example provided, but I don't think it's really necessary for this question.

Comment: `setNames( mylist , mynames )`

Comment: It can't be so simple ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the individual objects to appear in your environment then you can name the list using `setNames` and subsequently copy them into a named environment using `list2env`...

```
list2env( setNames( mylist , mynames ) , env = .GlobalEnv )
```

If you just want a named list then use `setNames`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
setNames(mylist, mynames)
```